# getListCellRendererComponent not called with JList<String>

Tags: templates, jlist, listcellrenderer

I created a class "MyJList" which extends JList. I use a DefaultListModel and a custom cell renderer called "MyListCellRenderer".

Here is a simple example which works well:

```
public class MyJList extends JList<String>{

    private DefaultListModel<String> myModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

    public MyJList(List<String> args){

        this.setModel(myModel);
        this.setCellRenderer(new MyListCellRenderer());

        if(args.size() > 0)
            for(String e : args)
                myModel.addElement(e);
    }


    public class MyListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean iss, boolean chf){  

            System.out.println("Function Called");
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value.toString(), index, iss, chf);

            return this;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(500, 500);

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("b");

        f.add(new MyJList(list));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It works well. The method getListCellRendererComponent is called to display the cells (several "Function called" are displayed in the output). However, I have the following warning:

```
JList is a raw type. References to generic type JList<E> should be parametrized.
```

I guess it is better to specify the type of the objects in the JList so I modify the following line:

```
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<String> list, String value, int index, boolean iss, boolean chf){
```

The trouble is that with this modification the method getListCellRendererComponent is not called anymore (no "Function called" in the output).

I don't understand why. Is it normal? If it is do you know how I can specify that the list contains String but that the getListCellRendererComponent must be called nevertheless?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to override a method, the parameters of the subclass-method have to be the same as those of the superclass. `JList` and `JList<String>` respectively `Object` and `String` are not of the same type, so the method of the subclass will not override the `getListCellRendererComponent()` method of the `DefaultListCellRenderer`. 
  (Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) about overriding methods.)
- If you want to avoid the warning, add a wildcard-symbol to the list
  type:
  `JList<?>`
  or add this before your method:
   `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`
- If you want to get the list item as a string just cast the 'value'-parameter, like:
  `String s = (String) value;`